# Axios Js (Vue) - 404 From Rest API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to use Vue for constructing an SPA, for this I choose Axios to send the HTTP requests.

My Backend was made using Django Rest Framework and it is working fine for all the routes. But when I tried to access it using Axios I got 404.

Here's the Javascript code:

```
function(){
            let today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)
            var instanceEncantt = axios.create({
                baseUrl: "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
                timeout:3000,
                headers:{'Authorization':'Authorization ab297cd9edb6eb2ea47818ccefdf28c994ff6e60'}
            })
            instanceEncantt.get(`/vendas/?`,{params:{data:today,id_loja_loja:this.form.store}})
            .then(response=>{
                alert("resp")
            })
            .catch(error=>{
                alert(""+error)
            });
        }
```

And the output at the alert says:

> Error: Request failed with status code 404

When I checked my backend logs, I found:

> [05/Feb/2018 17:42:57] "GET /sockjs-node/info?t=1517859777347 HTTP/1.1" 404 28030

And I have no idea why it is redirecting the request to this link. Also, at my Vue Debug Infos, I can find this line:

> [WDS] Disconnected!

If you need any other information, feel free to ask and I'll update the code.

Cheers,

Pedro.

Comment: are you certain the axios.get is directed to the right place? that the format of today and this.form.store matches the URL you're getting? alternately, have you tried increasing the timeout?

Comment: @LShapz Hi, first of all thank you for the answer. I don't think the timeout is the problem since I receive 404 from the server and I don't think the problem is the url path since I tried with other public APIS and I still get 404. I think maybe the problem is something up with npm dev and web-package config.

Comment: Can you reach antoher url from this API ?